# Why is compiler reporting partial move in error and not move?

Tags: rust

In the below program why does the compiler error mention partially moved and not just moved? How is partial move happening here from x to z? If &mut T doesn't implement Copy trait, it should be moved and not partial move?

```
fn main() {
    let mut y = 2;
    let x = Some(&mut y);
    match x {
        None => (),
        Some(z) => {
        *z = 3; 
        println!("{}", z)},
    };
    println!("{:?}",x);
}
```

Below is the error from the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a15d696efc16302643647dccd026ca32)

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0382]: borrow of partially moved value: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
6  |         Some(z) => {
   |              - value partially moved here
...
10 |     println!("{:?}",x);
   |                     ^ value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because value has type `&mut i32`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: borrow this field in the pattern to avoid moving `x.0`
   |
6  |         Some(ref z) => {
   |              ^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Because you are destructing `x` and moving the inner object?

Comment: But then its a move and not partial move?

Comment: Yes but you are not moving `x`, you are moving the part of `x`, `x` is not equal to `&mut T`. This [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move/partial_move.html) explains the reason better.

Comment: `x` is `Option<&mut i32>` and you are moving *only* the `&mut i32` into `z` -- the containing `Option` is not moved, thus it is partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the `Option` enum:

```rust
enum Option<T> {
    Some(T),
    None
}
```

Within that enum, `Some(T)` is actually a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs), containing one field.

When you use pattern matching to extract the value of the inner T, that would be a partial move of one field of the single field tuple struct `Some`.

A partial move of a field from a struct that only has one field might not seem useful, but more generally there could be any number of fields in the struct.

See also:

- Rust Reference section on [Enumerations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html)